# How to programmatically update a file uri in a node

Tags: 8, nodes, files

I'm programmatically moving a pdf file and then trying to update the uri in the node. Here's my code:

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$entity = $node->field_pdf->entity;
if ($entity) {
   $uri = $entity->getFileUri();
   // move the file and update the uri to the new location
   $entity->setFileUri($uri);
   $node->save();
}
```

The uri is correct--the file gets moved--but the node isn't saved with the updated uri. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to save the entity - not the node. Change `$node->save();` to `$entity->save();`

Comment: Thanks @100pic. Yes, that was it. Apparently, I didn't understand the full function of Node::load(). I thought it loads only nodes and not referenced entities also, but it seems that it must load referenced entities as well, else $entity->save() wouldn't work.

Comment: The node isnt changing, the entity is. That's why.